# Converting String arguments to StringBuffer

Tags: java, string, if-statement, append, stringbuffer

I want to use StringBuffer instead of concatenating string with the result. I used this code to convert the while loop but I am having trouble with the last if statement. What can I do to convert that?

Original code:

```
result = statement.executeQuery(sql);    
String string = "";

    while (result.next()) {
        string += result.getString(("Hello") + ",");
    }

    if (string!= null && !string.isEmpty()) {
        string= string.substring(0, string.length() - 1);
    }
```

My attempt:

```
result = statement.executeQuery(sql);
StringBuffer string = new StringBuffer("");

      while (result.next()) {
        string.append(("Hello") + ",")
      }

      if {
        --- CODE HERE ---
      }
```

Any help?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Just a note, `(("Hello") + ",")` is just going to evaluate to `"Hello,"`

Comment: Avoid concatenation of strings using "+=", but instead use StringBuffer to concatenate. I know how to append it like my attempt above, my only problem is how do I convert the if statement on the bottom to have it using StringBuffer instead of String?

Comment: StringBuffer is used if you need thread-safety. Maybe consider using StringBuilder. Also "*but I am having trouble with the last if statement.*" doesn't tell us much about problem you are facing.

Comment: [`deleteCharAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#deleteCharAt-int-)?  When in doubt, look at the javadoc for a class.  There's a good chance you will see what you need.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just trying to remove the last comma, try this:

```
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer("");
...
if ( buffer.length() > 0 ) {
    buffer.deleteCharAt( buffer.length() - 1 );
}
```

Comment: @ajb Yeah I was really confused.  There's a couple of really dubious ideas in that code, I think perhaps the OP didn't transcribe it well.

Comment: @markspace I agree, didn't even notice the `if` statement is technically useless in the OPs question - wonder if he will chime in and say what he really wants

Comment: @kingdamian42 Oh, dangit yeah you are right, I must be going crazy. (String.substring(...) doc: _The substring begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at index endIndex - 1_)

Answer (score 1):

```
    result = statement.executeQuery(sql);    
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    int length = result.size();

    if(result != null && length > 0)
    {
        while (result.next()) { 
            buffer.append(result.getString(("Hello"));
            if(--length > 0)
                buffer.append(",");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do with your if statement.

result = statement.executeQuery(sql);

StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");

```
  while (result.next()) {
    stringBuffer.append(("Hello") + ",")
  }

    if (stringBuffer.length()>0) {
        stringBuffer = new StringBuffer(stringBuffer.substring(0, stringBuffer.length() - 1));
    }
```

Comment: Why use `toString()` instead of just checking the buffer's length? The object exists because he created it right above so the null check does nothing, and there is a `length()` method on `StringBuffer`